# In Rails, How do I Validate that a User Has Access to Modify an Entry?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my rails app, I am using Devise which authenticates users in the app.  It gives me variables like `current_user.id` which is the current logged-in user's UserID.

In my app, every User is a member of at least one Group.  Any User can create one or many Trinkets and can assign each Trinket to one of their Groups.

So, here are my models:

```
User has_many :memberships
User has_many :groups, :through => :memberships

Group has_many :memberships
Group has_many :users, :through => :memberships
Group has_many :trinkets

Trinket belongs_to :group
```

So there are my models!  Everything is working great!

When a user updates a Trinket, they can assign that Trinket to one of their Groups.

BUT, there is a security flaw!  If someone views the Trinket/edit or Trinket/new page, copies the HTML source code, changes the values of the `<SELECT>` or `<INPUT>` tags in the form, they can actually submit their Trinket into someone else's GroupID.

I'd like to add a validation into the model or controller so it confirms the user really has access to use the submitted values before writing them to the database.  In this case, I want to see if the GroupID for this Trinket is a GroupID within `User.find(current_user.id).groups` but I cannot figure out how to do that validation in the Trinket model.

Anyone know how to verify that a user is trying to assign a value to something that actually have access to assign it to?  Does Devise or another gem have a way of checking associations for user submitted data?

The current Trinket model file just has:

```
attr_accessible :trinketname, :group_id
validates_presence_of :trinketname
```

Hope this makes sense.  Help is appreciated! :-)

Versions: Rails 3.2.13, Ruby 1.9.3p392, Devise 2.2.4.  I do have `protect_from_forgery` in my application_controller.rb file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put an `if` statement inside your action. This is probably not accurate but I hope it gets the point across:

```
 def create
   if trinket.group_id == current_user.group_id
     trinket.new(params[:trinket])
       if trinket.save
         redirect_to somewhere
       else 
         render :new
       end
   else      
    flash[:warn] "You're not allowed"
 end
```

Comment: you can add a check in the create and update action in the controller. something like if Tricket.group_id == current_user.group_id then do your create action else flash[:warn] "you're not allowed"

Comment: Thank you, iRichLau. That works!  Because my User-Group relationship is many-to-many, I had to do an array lookup instead of a direct `==` matching.  For `def create`: `if current_user.groups.include?(Group.find @trinket.group_id)` and for `def update`: `if current_user.groups.include?(Group.find params[:trinket][:group_id] )`. If the submitted data includes a group_id that the User not a member of, it returns false. If the submitted group_id does not exist in the database, it throws a ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound which was unintentional but acceptable because that is also a valid error. Yay!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is authorization.

Consider using one of the many available authorization frameworks to achieve your objective.

[`CanCan`](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) by Ryan Bates is one of the most extensively battle tested ones.

UPDATE: An [Ability](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities) can do:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    can :manage, Trinket, group: { id: user.group_ids }
  end
end
```

Comment: doesn't that seperate roles like users and admin. many users can have roles of users and they would be able to access it regardless.

Comment: Well, yes and no. While, it helps you segregate between different _types_ of users, a CanCan `Ability` for example, gives you a finer control over a `User`'s permissions as well. Look at the UPDATE above.

Comment: cool. that definitely works too. although if you don't need roles and just want to have a simple authorization. i would go with a helper method and put that where you'd like.

Comment: This is a huge help, and gets me going in the right direction. HOWEVER, I'm not using Groups to define what permissions a user has, I'm using Groups like storage buckets for the Trinkets. When someone goes to create a new Trinket, the above CanCan Ability would give permission denied, because the Trinket is not yet assigned to a Group.  Group assignment is done when the Trinket is created/updated.  I think the best option for me is to add some logic in the Trinket controller, to allow save only if the group_id attribute is within a list of User.find(current_user.id).groups.

Comment: Btw, I just used the CanCan gem to set up authorization on the Trinkets themselves.  CanCan now checks that the current user is a member of a group that the Trinket is in, then they are allowed to manage that Trinket.  Thanks for your suggestion, iRichLau